# How to use ActiveModel Dirty to keep Mailchimp in sync with my User model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mailchimp

I'd like to keep Mailchimp in sync with my user table.

I'd like to capture all of the devise fields (e.g. `current_sign_in_at`, `sign_in_count` etc) in the Mailchimp table and keep those up-to-date too.

The Mailchimp API integration is easy. What I want to know is how best to hook onto the `User` model, so that I can trigger my Mailchimp update method with the new record.

Also if anyone can explain why 'Dirty' is called that I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your first question, there are many callbacks ActiveRecord supplies that you can hook to in order to update Mailchimp as necessary. You can use after_create if you want to update Mailchimp only with new users and after_update if you want to update Mailchimp of an existing user data.
You can read the full documentation of callbacks [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Dirty is a common way to indicate that some data has changed but has not yet persisted. In ActiveRecord, it means that an attribute of a model has changed but has not been saved to the database yet.
So when I write `@some_user.username = 'some_user_name'` I made the `username` attribute of `@some_user` dirty. Once I issue `@some_user.save!` the attribute is persisted and no longer referred as dirty attribute.

The combination of both of this concepts is what you are looking for.
For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_update :update_mailchimp

  def update_mailchimp
    self.changed # => array of changed attributes
    self.changes # => hash of { attribute => [old_value, new_value] }
  end
end
```

I advice you to read the full documentation of [AR Dirty module](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html).